# Laravel routing : use comma without slash

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing

I'm building a website to list and search ads with Laravel 6.

Based on recommendations i i want to have "seo friendly" url looks like this :

https://myawesomewebsite.com/sale,shoes,new-york,xl,6,10.html

I tryied do to this :

```
Route::get('/sale,{slugs?}.html', 'AdsController@search')->where('slugs', '(.*)');
```

and this :

```
Route::get('/{slugs?}.html', 'AdsController@search')->where('slugs', '(.*)');
```

But i got a 404 error.

The only way i can make it works, it's like this :

https://myawesomewebsite.com/sale/shoes,new-york,xl,6,10.html

```
Route::get('/sale/{slugs?}.html', 'AdsController@search')->where('slugs', '(.*)');
```

But it's not what i want. How can i replace the first "/" by a "," between sale and {slugs?} ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested following:

```php
Route::get('/sale{slugs?}.html', function() {
    echo "Works!";
})->where('slugs', '(.*)');
```

It is working with `http://[host]/sale,shoes,new-york,xl,6,10.html`

However this is `Laravel 4.2.22` but I believe that should work for you as well.

Comment: Thanks. It's a good idea, but doesn't work. Still have a 404 for the url without /

Comment: Could you provide http access log output? Please also check Laravel log. This is working on my env I've tested it. I doubt it has something to do with the version of the framework.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didn't think to check the 404 error exception. I had an other route was putting the mess. So it works very well :)

Comment: It is kind a law of programming that the bug is where you least expect :)
Moreover, Laravel has some funny error handling so usually logs are first place to check for the problem.